# How to make foo().bake() works as foo.bake() using .prototype (?) in javascript?_

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance

Please have a look at this:

```
foo = function() {
    document.write("Unicorn <br>");
    return this; //This should return the foo Object every single time
};

//Now when I run foo(), it should display "Unicorn" and it does

foo();

​foo.bake = function() {
    document.write("Baked! <br>");
};

foo.bake();​​​​​​​​​​​​​


​foo.prototype.bake = foo.bake;

​foo().bake();​
```

The first time I run `foo()`, it writes out "Unicorn" as expected. Then I added new method into the existing foo Object (method `bake()` which writes out "Baked!", and it works, too. Then I tried to added the same method, but this time, using .prototype, and ***IF*** I understand it correctly, now `foo().bake` should be the same function as `foo.bake`.

I've searched many articles on StackOverflow about how jQuery could behave as an Object and Function at the same time. I read and understood the answers given but they did not solve my problem.

My question: How could I make `foo().bake()` work the same as `foo.bake()`. Is it possible?

Thanks everyone in advanced._

Comment: A naked `foo()` would more than likely return the global object (`window`?) rather than a `foo`.  In order to use the function as a constructor, you'll probably have to say `new foo()`.

Comment: Could you please make it clear for me? I am really confused about those._

Comment: `foo()` just calls the function.  Since you haven't said `new`, it isn't being treated as a constructor.  It doesn't get a `this` to construct, and `this` ends up being what it is by default (the global object).  `new foo()` creates an object, and then calls `foo` with `this` set to the new object.  It also sets properties that tell it what the object's prototype is, which `foo()` alone won't (since it's not being used as a constructor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the correct way to use constructor and the instance.

```
foo = function() {
    document.write("Unicorn <br>");
    /*
    * If foo works as a constructor, "this" refer to the instance.
    * e.g. this.name = 'Foo No.1';
    *
    * If foo works as a function, "this" refer to the current scope which 
    *  is the window object in your case .
    */
    return this; 
};

//Used as constructor
var fooInstance = new foo();

//Used as function
alert(foo() == window)       //alerts true
```

In fact, you don't have to return anything in your constructor, the only thing you need to do is to use the `new` keyword.

So in your case, modified the last statement to:
`(new foo()).bake();`

Answer (score 2):

As @Grant Zhu points out, you are not using the constructor of foo but the function foo. modifying last statement to: `(new foo()).bake();` fixes the problem.

Another way to fix it, which I have found to be very useful, is to force a function to act as the constructor like so:

```
Something = function() {
  if (false === (this instanceof Something)) {
    return new Something();
  }
  ...
};
```

Then `Something()` behaves exactly the same way as `new Something()`

I don't know what you think of this pattern, I found it somewhere on the web and use it ever since in my constructors. Can anyone here see any problems with it?

Comment: The main problem i see is, it's lying to you.  `Something()` shouldn't even exist, IMO, much less pretend it's a constructor.  If i were to do something even remotely like this, i'd have `Something()` throw an exception...just so i'm told quite bluntly when a constructor isn't being treated like one.